# How to emulate a button click from another class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, emulation

I have a button defined in my main activity that will speak a string value. when I click the button
It speaks the string value. I also have a broadcast receiver defined in another non-activity
class( KOTLIN  CLASS ).
When the broadcast is received, I want to emulate the button click in the main activity so that I can
Have a different message spoken. I am using kotlin in the android studio.

All of my code works. I only need to know how to trigger the main activity button from another class.

I hope that this is possible to do.

I tried calling the button `callonclick()` from the non-activity class and it crashes the app.

I can call the button `callonclick()` from the mainactivity class and it works fine.

So what I am doing is calling the `clickButton()` function in the mainActivity class from another class.

In my non-activity class, I have the following code:

```
var mActivity = MainActivity()
mActivity.clickButton() // calling the onclick function in the Main act
```

the above statement gets to the onclick function and then crashes
when the `btnSpeak!!.callOnClick()` statement is executed.

Here is the onclick function in the mainactivity class

```
public fun clickButton() {      

   println("IN ClickButton *********************************")

   btnSpeak!!.callOnClick()  
}
```

When I click the button in the mainactivity class the the onclick function works fine and speaks my message.

Comment: This seems to me more of a design problem, in that the code that does the action should be in a separate object which can then be called either from the button click or from somewhere else. That is, you shouldn't need to "click a button" in code for an action, just trigger the action directly.

Comment: As a new android kotlin user, I did not realize that you could define the broadcast receiver in the main activity. Once I defined the receiver under the main activity, I was able to emulate the button click from my broadcast functions. All of the examples of my broadcast receiver that I saw were in separate Kotlin files. So, that is how I defined my receiver - huge mistake. All is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to receive a broadcast, and once it's received you want to click a button.

First of all, you can't create new instances of your activity manually. Activity triggered only by intents.

But you're already inside `MainActivity`, so you don't need to navigate to it or create a new instance of the activity to get access to its method.

All you need is:

1. To create an `interface`:

   ```
   interface MyBroadcastListener {
       fun click()
   }
   ```
2. Implement it in your activity:

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyBroadcastListener {
        ...

        override fun click() {
            btnSpeak?.callOnClick()
        }
   }
   ```
3. Then, pass listener as receiver constructor argument:

   ```
   class MyReceiver(private val listener: MyBroadcastListener) : BroadcastReceiver() {
       override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
           listener.click()
       }
   }
   ```
4. In `MainActivity` in a place where you register the receiver pass `this` as a constructor parameter:

   ```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       val receiver = MyReceiver(this)
       // TODO: register receiver
   }
   ```